# Change page layout of a magento page without editing core files

Tags: magento-1.7

I have read [how to change product view page to one column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190678/how-to-change-product-view-page-to-one-column-layout), but is there any other way than this so that we do not have to edit the core files as on update these files will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in the following way also. I think it gives us more control and that's what I needed.

Edit:

**app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml**

Add the following there:

```
<customer_account_login>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to go:

**CMS->pages->your page**

Select Design, and change the layout there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good way but its the way iv been modifying magento, if it is wrong please someone explain the correct way.

say you want to edit this file

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php

you would copy it to . . .

> app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Abstract.php

then make your changes.

same with template and layout files.

say you want to change

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

you would copy it to

> app/design/frontend/CompanyName/ThemeName/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

and make your changes

just make sure in the magento admin configuration you have your theme set up correctly.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is a correct way to do (as I am also a new bee), because doing this beats the benefits of OOP like DRY and all...